# Spring @RequestMapping with regex doesn't work with POST?

Tags: regex, spring

Can I use regex in a @RequestMapping with the request type is POST?

I tried it:

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "/index/{prePath:^tutor$|^admin$}", method = RequestMethod.POST )
```

With my form

```
<form:form action="../index/admin.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="mod">
```

But the message is `WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer replace the regex with `{prePath:^tutor.do$|^admin.do$}` seems the extension is also needed.

The other controller works fine without the `.do` extension though